# grep, sort column form files

Tags: bash, sorting, csv, grep

I have x.csv files (numbered from 1 to x), they consist with two columns, like this:

```
sometext somedigits

... ...

500 1 

501 2 

502 3 

... ... 

900 y

end
```

All  I am trying to do is write a bash script that could sort those csv files by ascending name and output one file (with added multiple columns) with result from [500..900] other files, so it should look like:

```
500 1 .. 1x

501 2 .. 2x

...

900 y .. yx
```

I hope you understand what I have in mind. It is simple but gets over my head.

Example:

...

550,0.000158823324663182

551,0.00015425166406236

553,0.000141510750525255

554,0.000137520666699473

555,0.000131489691198977

...

This is how output looks like (first column is like array from [500..900], second column is result (digits)). I am trying to add second columns from the rest of the x.csv files (in ascending order) in one file.

Comment: Can you give us a full concrete example with just 2-3 input files each having 3-4 rows (and the full expected output, of course)?  And if you have any code so far, let  us see that too.

Comment: what do u mean by files by ascending name

Comment: code i was using so far (but it is wrong): grep [500..900] *.csv | sort -n >test.txt

Comment: undoubtedly, you want to use the [`join`](http://man.cx/join) command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] " " $2} END {for( i in a ) print i a[i]}' *.csv | sort -n
```

Comment: As I do understand awk is more flexible and I could use it like variable in array..